# Declare variable to be initialized in Module1 and used in UserForm module

Tags: vba, excel, global-variables

I have a project with one module (`main`) and one userform module (`myUserForm`).
I declare the variable as global on top of the module `main`:

```
Dim myGlobal As MyType
```

... then I set my variable inside module `main`:

```
Public Sub mySubInMain()
    Set myGlobal = New MyType
End Sub
```

... but when I try to use it in the module `myUserForm`:

```
Private Sub oneSubOfTheForm()
    myGlobal.Name = "something"
End Sub
```

... I get `Object required` exception. How should I declare my variable `myGlobal` to live in the other stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable is in a module called `main`, and you declare it `Public`, i.e.

```
Public myGlobal As MyType
```

you should be able to refer to it in your UserForm as `main.myGlobal` (or simply as `myGlobal`, but it is usually better to qualify it so that it is obvious where it resides).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Public property in a standard module to get the object so you can control its state.

```
Option Explicit
Private type_ As CustomType

Public Property Get MyType() As CustomType
    If type_ Is Nothing Then Set type_ = New CustomType
    Set MyType = type_
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign to `myGlobal` something, as exception states. So, you have to first call `mySubInMain`, then you can use `myGlobal` object.